# Page not found in Laravel, routes problem

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a problem with my Laravel and probably routes but I'm not sure.

So, there is a contact form in modal window. When I click on `Send` button I've got page not found error.

What I have in the `web.php` is

```
Route::post('/apply_now','HomeController@apply_now')->name('apply_now');
```

In the `HomeController.php`

```
public function apply_now(Request $request)
{
     ... form fields data

     return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'Sent');
}
```

And the form

```
{{Form::open(array('route'=>'apply_now','files' => true,'method'=>'post'))}}
   ...
   form field

{{Form::close()}
```

The error

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /apply_now was not found on this server.

I don't see anything wrong with the routes but yet can't find the problem.

UPDATE:

```
|        | POST                                   | apply_now                                           | apply_now                          | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@apply_now
```

UPDATE 2. The modal

```
<!-- Apply Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="apply" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="applyModalLable">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title text-center" id="applyModalLable">Apply Now</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="POST" action="https://example.com/apply_now" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="OyEdnHIWRgbZmPo0joodNmWraDSuuACIrwqup044">
                
                    <div class="form-group ">
                         <input type="text" name="your_name" class="form-control" placeholder="*Your Name" value="" >                         
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group  ">
                        <label>*Country</label>
                        <input type="text" name="country" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Country" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <input type="text" name="contact_email" class="form-control" placeholder="*Contact Email" >                          
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group ">
                        <input type="text" name="contact_phone" class="form-control" placeholder="*Contact Phone">                          
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group text-center">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-custom btn-sm btn-block">Submit</button>
                    </div> 
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: share output from `php artisan route:list` ?

Comment: @NikleshRaut I've updated it with the part for apply_now. It has lot's of lines that's why I've put only the one with the problem

Comment: `->name('apply_now')` remove this and try. `php artisan route:clear` and `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: When I remove it I've got `Route [apply_now] not defined. `

Comment: put your web.php data here.

Comment: Did you add `csrf_token()` into the form?

Comment: There is already token when I check source of the page.

Comment: what's your laravel version ?

Comment: "laravel/framework": "5.6.*",

Comment: are you using some package for html blade building ?

Comment: this type of html building is available only in 4.2 version could you give me link for 5.6 of official website if you have regarding html making in this manner .

Comment: also there bracket missing here " {{Form::close()}  "  should like this {{Form::close()}}       or {!! Form::close() !!} @Jordan

Comment: Have you tried naming your route differently? Like `->name('applynow')`

Comment: @kerbholz, yes, same error.

Comment: did you see this  " \Hometroller@apply_now " ?

Comment: Yes, now is HomeController@apply_now.

Comment: could you post your html end result

Comment: @GauravGupta, sorry which result - of the form?

Comment: output of above code "form"  , also one more this is there any url working ?

Comment: Yes, it is one page website. On the home page there are 2 forms - Apply and Contact. Both are with modals. The contact form works perfectly, while the Apply one doesn't work.

Comment: I've updated the question with the modal window and form in it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191707/discussion-between-gaurav-gupta-and-jordan).

Comment: just a hunch . try with index.php in between

Answer (score 1):

make routes like this:

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'],'/apply_now', 'HomeController@apply_now');
```

Comment: Got this `Route [apply_now] not defined.`

Comment: Still same error. Even after deleting the files in bootstrap/cache

Comment: Same `"Route [apply_now] not defined.`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is no error in the code, can you clear the cache;

```
php artisan route:cache
```

---

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Pt2l.png)

Did you see the area in the picture?

Comment: Yes, indeed, I've fixed it but the output is still not found

Comment: Try this command.
`php artisan optimize`
`php artisan cache:clear` 
`php artisan route:cache`
`php artisan view:clear`
`php artisan config:cache`

Answer (score 1):

Try Adding

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

This will add the CRSF Token field to your form

eg. `<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="SomeRandomString">`

which is required by laravel ,CSRF is enabled by default on all Routes to check if the post request is secure , you can also disable it from  **VerifyCsrfToken.php**  which is middleware located at

```
app\Http\Middleware
```

To Disable the CRSF for your route
update

```
protected $except = [
        //
        'apply_now'
    ];
```

Disabling this is not a good practice, If you want your application secure

Add

```
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

In your form for.eg.

```
{{ Form::open(array('route'=>'apply_now','files' => true,'method'=>'post')) }}
   ...
   form field
    {{ csrf_field() }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Now once you submit the form laravel will check if crsf token is sent with the form and let your request proceed further

Comment: try with little bit of expiation too. why should we change and what's wrong in above code :)

Comment: Well Basically its a security token, which is checked by laravel for every post request  adding it to a form will let the laravel know that the form submitted is having token .

Comment: i know that. i m saying that you should explain your answer so that it esay to understand. you can use token like this also @csrf

Comment: @RajdeepTayde, there is already security token even without I add {{ csrf_field() }}

Comment: are you running it on localhost

Answer (score 0):

Run this command and try again

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

or

remove all files from the

```
/bootstrap/cache
/storage/framework/cache/data
/storage/framework/sessions
/storage/framework/views
```

and make sure you have defined both urls into web.php file something like this:

```
Route::post('/','HomeController@index');
Route::post('apply_now','HomeController@apply_now')->name('apply_now');
```

and make sure your server has turned on mod rewrite. So Laravel can handle .htaccess rules.

Comment: I can't run this on shared hosting.. or I can?

Comment: Then can you try to remove all files the /bootstrap/cache directory and check again

Comment: I've deleted them. Reloaded but still same. And in the cache directory there new files now

Comment: Tried all the mentioned things and same - apply_now not found.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this,

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

In your controller

```
return redirect()->route('home')->with('message', 'Sent');
```

Hope this helps :)